# objects .each method in ruby, lets me read values from object, but won't let me write values to it. Scoping issue?

Tags: ruby

So I wrote a 2D array class for a project I'm working on, in Ruby.

It's simple enough: the `initialize` creates a Square 2D array, of a size dictated by its argument, called `@contents`.

I overload the `[]` operator to make the data within the object accessible, like so:

```
def [] (x, y)
  @contents[x][y]
end

def []=(x, y, z)
  @contents[x][y] = z
end
```

I add an `each` method to it, so that I could mix in the enumerable module, and give it some functionality, like so:

```
def each
  i, j =0,0
  while (i<@size)
    while(j<@size)
      yield @contents[i][j]
      j+=1
    end
    i, j = i+1, 0
  end
end
```

and I gave it a `to_s` method, like so:

```
def to_s
  @contents.each{|i| puts i}
end
```

Now, I create a new instance of this 2D array object in a new file, and try to populate it. Initally,I did this manually, with nested loops, like so:

```
j, i, k= 0, 0, 0
puts " size = #{@size}"
while (i<@size)
  while(j<@size)
    @2Darray[i,j], k, j= @array[k], k+1, j+1
  end
  i, j=i+1, 0
end
```

And that works just fine. the to_s method will print out the array perfectly. I realized though, that these nested loops might not have been the 'ruby way' and tried to do it with itterators. I had already implimented an `each` method, so I tried to subsitute the above, with the following:

```
j=0
@2Darray.each{|i|
  i = @array[j]
  j += 1
  break unless j < size
}
```

But, unfortunately, this doesn't work. It runs just fine, but when the to_s is called, it prints line after line of nothing. ie, it prints out an array of empty arrays.

I thought it was my .each method, but that works fine when the to_s method calls it. I thought it might have been my `[]=` method, but that works fine when I use nested while-loops.

Now I'm thinking it must be a problem with scoping. in my each-loop above, `|i|` is a local variable, am I right? So that I assign the value of `array[j]` to `i`, but i is just a copy of the (empty) position which I want to fill, yes?

So, firstly, am I on the right track, or is my problem somewhere else entirely? If so, where, if not: How can I modify my each-loop above, to make assignments to the data within @2Darray, instead of just changing the value of the `|i|` place-holder.

Apologies for my verbouseness, and thank you for your time! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As an aside, your `to_s` implementation doesn't make sense, it should be returning a String, not dumping a bunch of stuff to the standard output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@2Darray.each{|i| i=@array[j]
```

That is not the way you can populate whatever @2Darray is. `i` is a block local variable. The #each method effectivelly calls your block (the iterator) for every element, passing a reference to the element in that block local variable. Assigning to a variable will not change the object the variable had been pointing to previously.

The "ruby way" to populate it would be to provide an instance method that accepts the data to be used, that then uses whatever loop is appropriate.

For what it's worth, your `while(i<@size)` loops can well be expressed as `@size.times`

Comment: Would size.times be better than while (i<@size)?? 

I mean, I know the loop condition has to be tested size times when you use the while, but is there no equivelent in .times? ie would using size.times save you size operations... or do you just think it's a more readable way to write the loop?

Comment: It wouldn't be faster (most likely), but it is definitely _way_ better style than using a while.

Answer (score 1):

Consider how Ruby populates normal Arrays.

```
a = Array.new(4) {|i| i**2}
=> [0,1,4,9]
```

I.e. your code should go in initialize, rather than each. Making `each` alter the object in place would be poor design, because that's not how it works for other enumerable objects. If you want to alter the elements in-place, take inspiration from `Array#map!`.

As for how to implement these methods, it's okay to use traditional `while` and `for` loops. That's the whole point of defining methods: hiding the gritty details from the programmer so they don't have to worry about it!

Comment: Yeah, only that _some_ programmer will have to maintain the implementation, so that's a poor excuse for bad coding styles.

Comment: I see what you mean. The while loop (that works) is in initalize now, i just thought there would be a more fitting approach.